# combining two SQL SELECT COUNT(*) statements

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm using Microsoft Access 2007. I have two SELECT COUNT(*) statements which run ok without combining, but I want to combine those statements to use as a form recordsource via VBA.

```
1. SELECT Count(*) AS OrderCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo FROM tblDisposition);"

2. SELECT Count(*) AS ReviewCount FROM tblDisposition WHERE [ReviewClose]=0;
```

I know there are already lot of this kind of question such as :

[two SQL COUNT() queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888731/two-sql-count-queries)

[Access 2007: "SELECT COUNT(DISCTINCT ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330639/access-2007-select-countdisctinct)

[How do I combine 2 select statements into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542705/how-do-i-combine-2-select-statements-into-one)

and many more. Here's what I've tried but still failed:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS OrderCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo FROM tblDisposition)),"
        (SELECT Count(*) AS ReviewCount FROM tblDisposition WHERE [ReviewClose]=0);"
```

I set the combined SQL statement on myForm as recordsource and I have two textfields which I set the controlsource as OrderCount and ReviewCount. On form load event which I set the recorsource, both textfields give #NAME error but if I set only either one SQL statement, it will display the correct count on the textfield.

Comment: @AmitSingh i set the combined SQL statement on myForm. and i have two textfields which i set the controlsource as OrderCount and ReviewCount. when runs,both textfields give #NAME error. but if i set only either one SQL statement,it will display the correct count on the textfield.

Comment: provide column alias name and than try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get both counts as two values in a single row using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT Count(*) AS OrderCount 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo FROM tblDisposition
            )
    ) AS OrderCount,
    (
        SELECT Count(*) AS ReviewCount 
        FROM tblDisposition 
        WHERE [ReviewClose]=0
    ) AS ReviewCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblDisposition
    )
```

Note that the final `FROM` clause is really just a way to get the query to return a single row. This could also have been done with a `Dual` table, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933518/table-less-union-query-in-ms-access-jet-ace/7933927#7933927).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your query isn't working at all. Try adding '* FROM' like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT Count(*) AS OrderCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo FROM tblDisposition)),
(SELECT Count(*) AS ReviewCount FROM tblDisposition WHERE [ReviewClose]=0)
```

Comment: using this,now i get the 'run-time error 3074: cannot repeat table name '%$##@_Alias' in FROM clause'

Comment: Waht aliases are you using?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760180.aspx Try adding different.